# Cannot convert string to bool, but there is no bool?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a simple viewmodel to count logins that is populated by the following:

```
    public ActionResult LoginCount()
    {
        IQueryable<LoginGroup> data = from sysAction in db.SysActions
                                           //where movie.
                                      where sysAction.ActionType = "Login"
                                           group sysAction by System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(sysAction.Date) into LoginGroup
                                           select new LoginGroup()
                                           {
                                               Date = LoginGroup.Key,
                                               LoginCount = LoginGroup.Count(),
                                           };
        return View(data.ToList());
    }
```

It works except when I add in the where clause to pull out only actiontypes with a value of "Login".  There is no bool being used.  Why the error?

Comment: You need `==`, not `=` for comparison.

Comment: ahh, can't believe I missed that.  Thanks for the help.  Repost and I'll give you the answer.  Geez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When checking values you need to make use of `==` and not `=`. They have 2 very different uses. `==` is for checking one value against another value and `=` is for assignment purposes.

So in your case you can try the following:

```
public ActionResult LoginCount()
{
     IQueryable<LoginGroup> data =
          from sysAction in db.SysActions
          where sysAction.ActionType == "Login"
          group sysAction by TruncateTime(sysAction.Date)
               into LoginGroup
               select new LoginGroup()
               {
                    Date = LoginGroup.Key,
                    LoginCount = LoginGroup.Count()
               };

     return View(data.ToList());
}
```

I hope this helps.